# Case feed unable to auto include CC list & email template unalble to load body text

Tags: case, email2case

Hi i have case feed & email to case enabled  in my salesforce org. i have a situation where my customer send in email to my routing email and CC some other ppl.

In case feed, when i select answer customer the CC list member is gone, how can i remain the CC list from the original email?

And i have a email template which will load the message body -> {!EmailMessage.TextBody} but it wont load the body. any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Apex class as the [InboundEmailHandler](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/An_Introduction_To_Email_Services_on_Force.com) or the old email2case (where you had to install an agent within your network)?

If it's Apex - are you sure you save the addresses on the EmailMessage record?

Something like this:

```
EmailMessage newEmail = new EmailMessage(
  FromAddress = email.fromAddress,
  FromName = email.fromName,

  ToAddress = (email.toAddresses == null || email.toAddresses.isEmpty() ? '' : String.join(email.toAddresses, ', ').abbreviate(4000)),
  CcAddress = (email.ccAddresses == null || email.ccAddresses.isEmpty() ? '' : String.join(email.ccAddresses, ', ').abbreviate(4000)),

  // skipping some stuff...

  Subject = email.subject,
  Incoming = true,
  MessageDate = System.now(),
  Status = '0',
  ParentId = caseId);
```

Last but not least: I don't have an org handy where I'd have both email2case and Chatter but if you click the standard buttons there's a difference between "Reply" and "Reply to all" ;)

Comment: P.S. About the body - was there only HTML body by any chance?